# Triangulation of 2-Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

I am reading John Lee's "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" and in chapter 5 he states:

> Theorem 5.36 (Triangulation Theorem for 2-Manifolds). Every 2-manifold
> is homeomorphic to the polyhedron of a 2-dimensional simplicial
> complex, in which every 1-simplex is a face of exactly two
> 2-simplices.
>
> The proof is highly technical and beyond our scope, so we can only
> describe some of the main ideas here (etc.)

This was a bit disappointing since this theorem is central in proving his classification theorem of compact 2-manifolds in chapter 6. Thus I decided to look up on the net if there were some proofs and came up across this link: [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/doylemoran.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/doylemoran.pdf)

Which seems to prove that all compact 2-manifolds are triangulable and the paper seems to date back to 1967 (I haven't read it yet, I want to confirm its legitimacy). Now I realize that Theorem 5.36 refers to all 2-manifolds not just compact ones but given that he's specifically classifying compact manifolds why did he not include the above (seemingly short) proof if it is indeed a legitimate one? Or is it because the second part of the claim in Theorem 5.36 (i.e. "in which every 1-simplex is a face of exactly two 2-simplices") that is technical and hard to prove?

Comment: The answer says it all. However, I find that even accepting the Jordan-Schoenflies theorem the proof is still technical. In particular, I have not found a proof of the other "familiar" facts they use, ref. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236146/reference-for-familiar-facts-from-geometric-topology-triangulation-of-compact-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second part is very easy. I recommend as an exercise that you show this is true of any polyhedron homeomorphic to a surface.

The point is that the paper you link is not a complete reference: it pushes the problem back to needing a proof of the Schoenflies theorem, which is technical no matter how you slice it.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thanks for clarifying the issue.