# Reference for Familiar Facts from Geometric Topology, Triangulation of Compact 2-Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

In [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/doylemoran.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/doylemoran.pdf), there is a short proof that compact 2 manifolds can be triangulated.

In it, they list two facts that I never heard before but they claim to be familiar. It's copied below.

The first one is intuitive, but since we're not assuming smooth structures we may not have a tubular neighborhood. Would someone have a proof for it?

The second one I think is straight-forward, but the way he writes makes me second-guess if I understand the statement right. A cellular set seems to be just any 2-cell, or a point. Am I missing something? Why this whole gadget of infinite intersections?

[image]

The definition of 2-cell is any topological space that is homeomorphic to the closed unit disk.

Comment: An arc, or more generally a tree, is also a cellular set. And then stuff like tree-like chains of discs, ...

Comment: Did you mean to write more with the ellipsis?

Comment: No, I meant to indicate, as an ellipsis often indicates, that the list goes on and on and on and on and....

Comment: Could you explain more? I don’t see how this leads to a proof.

Comment: I'm not suggesting a proof of anything. I'm informing you that there are many, many, many cellular subsets that are not 2-cells, and therefore the whole premise of your paragraph "The second one..." is faulty.